# MVC 5 connectionstring oracle

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Доброго дня!

Создал веб-морду которая подключается через модель ADO.NET EDM к БД на оракле (Code First на основе существующей базы данных).
Подключение к БД проходит под пользователем который указан в connectionstring:

web.config

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Model1" connectionString="Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=ххх.ххх.ххх.ххх)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=**tnsname**)));User Id=**USER1**;Password=**123**;"
  providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Model1

```
   public Model1()
            : base("name=Model1")
        {}
```

Но цель стоит, чтобы пользователи могли авторизоваться из под веб под своими логинами, а не жестко были прописаны в connectionStrings.

Возможно ли сделать такое динамичное подключение c ораклом? (все это крутиться на IIS)

Comment: Если оракл понимает ActiveDirectory то возможно использовать авторизацию в ASP.NET через AD.

Comment: AD к сожалению не используется (

Comment: Тогда без костылей наверное не обойтись. (